# Why does WordPress generate double slash when uploading images?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have an existing WordPress instance that generates an extra slash when I upload an image. I'm not sure what's happening but this is causing me issues when I try to validate an image for Twitter.

e.g.

https://www.mydomain.com.au//home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/PODCAST-PIC.jpg

The // in front of home is causing issues. Is there a setting or something that I'm missing?

I'm on Wordpress 5.3.2 hosted on CPanel.

More information:

I'm uploading it normally through the media section. The moment I've uploaded it, the `copy link` property of the image already contains the double slashes. So I've not done anything to the image yet but uploaded it.

I believe it might be something to do with my settings but I'm not 100% sure where to look into.

Comment: How are you retrieving your image url?

Comment: On your general settings page, do your WordPress and Site addresses have trailing slashes?

Comment: They do not have trailing slashes

Comment: How is your 'Settins > General > Wordpress URL' it is `https://www.mydomain.com.au/home/username/public_html` or `https://www.mydomain.com.au`? have you defined any `define( 'WP_HOME', '...' );` or `define( 'WP_SITEURL', '...' );` on your `wp-config.php` file?